# Removing thesis title and author name from abstract

Tags: templates, abstract, author

I am using this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl

I have already turned on `consistentlayout`, but it keeps displaying author name and thesis title in the abstract. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide an MWE. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to your header (I put them right before the "Margin settings" comment):

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{ O{} }{%
    \addchap*{\abstractname}%
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces
}%
{}
```

For comparison, the code executed by the template when the option `consistentlayout` is set (from [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)):

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{ O{} }{%
    \addchap*{\abstractname}%
    {\chapteralign\normalsize\abstractauthorfont \authorname \par} % Author name
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    {\chapteralign\parbox{.7\linewidth}{\chapteralign\normalsize\itshape\abstracttitlefont\@title}\par}% Thesis title
    \bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces
}%
{}
```

So I just removed the lines that insert the author name and thesis title into the abstract page.

Answer (score 3):

The [simplest possible](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/#i-want-to-change-the-layout-of-predefined-abstractdeclarationetc-page) way would be to use

```
\addchap{Abstract} 

Abstract text here
```

Instead of redefining some commands